# Survival analysis for multiple distinct outcomes

Tags: statistics, survival-analysis

I have been playing around a Kaplan Meier Survival analysis. I have 3 conditions mutually exclusive. Let says:

1. condition 1 is 'I am not able to work (and not working)'
2. condition 2 is 'I am able to work and I am working'
3. condition 3 is 'I am able to work but I am not working'

I am trying to have an overall likelihood to be either way in C1, C2 or C3.
I have done 3 separates Survival analysis (one for each condition) and add the cumulative proportion for the same time,  but to the total is slightly superior to 1 (between 1.02 to 1.06 to be exact). I was wondering how to explain this over estimation. Is it something in my logic or the way the censored data are estimated? (or else).
Thanks,

Comment: Depending on methodology, the difference could be the result of accumulated rounding error.